# Ideas for displaying instructions on assembly work stations

Tags: monitors, wireless

I am looking for ways to introduce electronic work instructions to employees on production work station. Each working station needs to have a different set of instructions displayed for the worker to follow. Currently we are using printed paper but its a hassle when changing or updating it. My current solution is buying a few pairs of cheap monitors and raspberries and use VNC to display the instructions, but I was wondering if there are better ways of doing this. Cost and ease of deployment are a factor. The format of the instructions is not an issue, it can be pdf, jpeg, ... The perfect gadget would be some cheap wifi monitor which only displays still images. Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 0):

I´m not able to comment on your post, so I will write an answer.

I think I would go with the Raspberry Pi solution. This sounds like the cheapest and most configurable option.

Are you changing the instructions over VNC? Because here you might be able to use some script to show the latest instruction. :)